# Command returns a list of strings, but want to make it an array so I can iterate through them

Tags: bash, git

I have this command which gives me a list of directories that have had changes in them when comparing two different git branches:

```
git diff test production --name-only | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u

k8s
postgres
scripts
```

I want to iterate through the values it returns (in this case `k8s`, `postgres`, and `scripts`).

I can't figure out how to convert these values to an array though. I've tried a couple things:

```
changedServices=$(git diff test production --name-only | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u)
```

Which just treats it as a multiline string.

And the following with the error message...

```
declare -a changedServices=$(git diff test production --name-only | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u)

declare: changedServices: inconsistent type for assignment
```

How would I go about parsing this list as an array?

Comment: Bash or zsh? The answer you refer to is zsh specific.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ultimately, this is going to end up in a CI/CD pipeline and looking at the Azure DevOps Pipeline documentation briefly, I don't see anything about it taking `zsh` commands. So this will need to be a `bash` more than likely.

Comment: Then the `mapfile` answer should work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var=$()` is a string assignment. For arrays you don't include the `$`, but you can also use mapfile as it's generally a better option

```
mapfile -t changedServices < <(git diff test production --name-only | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u)
```

The `-t` option removes trailing delimiters.

If you don't have mapfile, another thing you can do is

```
changedServices=()

while IFS= read -r line; do
    changedServices+=("${line}")
done < <(git diff test production --name-only | awk -F'/' 'NF!=1{print $1}' | sort -u)
```

Comment: To read a line verbatim: `while IFS= read -r line` -- without `IFS=`, then leading and trailing IFS characters are removed: `printf "   %s   \n" foo bar | { read -r first; IFS= read -r second; declare -p first second; }`